# How can I get the nanoc SASS filter to use SCSS syntax?

Tags: ruby, nanoc

In my nanoc site, I want to specify my styles using SCSS:

```
p {
  em {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

... not SASS:

```
p 
  em 
    color: red
```

But if I try using SCSS, I get a compile error from the SASS filter. How do I get it to use SCSS?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This turned out to be quite simple:

```
filter :sass, syntax: :scss
```

Filters in nanoc seem to follow the pattern of taking any options they're given and passing them along to whatever object actually does the work. For instance, `Nanoc::Filters::Sass` does this in its `run` method:

```
def run(content, params={})
  options = params.dup
  # supply default options, etc...
  engine = ::Sass::Engine.new(content, options)
  # ...
  engine.render
end
```

`Sass::Engine`, in turn, has `:syntax` as an [available option](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#options).

Comment: With Compass you can also whack all the options in a ```config.rb``` file: ```Compass.add_project_configuration('config.rb')``` then in the rules you instead just pass it the whole set: ```filter :sass, Compass.sass_engine_options```

Comment: Note: If you need this to work on Ruby 1.8.x, use the older hash syntax instead: `:syntax => :scss` (I hadn't noticed until yesterday that Ruby 1.9.2 introduced a new hash syntax)